# sharing image on Pinterst from bundle getting not valid url format

Tags: ios, pinterest

getting "Error Invalid parameter 'source_url' (value /var/mobile/Applications/DB373DAD-8D47-.....A5/PintItDemo.app/shareImage.png) is not a valid URL format."

I just want to pin image from my device on Pinterest.so i have just retrieved the url of image from NSBundle for resource and passed that path as below

```
NSString* stringURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"imageToPin" ofType:@"png"];
[_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]
                           sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]
                         description:@"Pinning from my app"];
```

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, your URL `/var/mobile/Applications/DB373DAD-8D47-.....A5/PintItDemo.app/shareImage.png` is not a valid URL. Clearly because it is starting with `/var/mo...`.
Please try a valid URL like:

> https://www.xyz.com/var/mobile/Applications/DB373DAD-8D47-A5/PintItDemo.app/shareImage.png

**EDIT:**
For a Pinterest ['Pin it' button](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/) to work, there needs to be a universally accessible image url, which can be passed to the 'Pin it' link's `href` attribute.
So, you can upload the image to the server and create a url which can be passed to the 'Pin it' button.

A 'Pin it' button is just a static link. There might be a way using [Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/api_docs/) to upload an image to Pinterest and then sharing the same image. But that would be a whole different thing.

Comment: Thanks to reply But i need to share from my device,not from server.then how to make valid url?